# C++11 - What is wrong with this use of decltype function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, decltype

While trying to implement a **Delegate**-class using variadic templates I ran into a problem I'm unable to solve:

```
/// --------------------------------------
/// @thanks     God
///             Steve Reinalter
/// @author     Henri Korpela aka Helixirr
/// --------------------------------------
#include <cstdio>

template<typename>
class Delegate;

template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
class Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>{
public:

    /// Constructors & destructors:
    Delegate(void) = default;
    Delegate(Delegate const& delegate_) = default;
    Delegate(Delegate&& delegate_) = default;

    /// Member functions:
    Delegate& bind(Return (*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...));
    template<class C>
    Delegate& bind(C& c_, Return (C::*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...));

    /// Member functions (overloaded operators, assignment):
    Delegate& operator=(Delegate const& delegate_) = default;
    Delegate& operator=(Delegate&& delegate_) = default;

    /// Member functions (overloaded operators, function call):
    inline Return operator()(Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_) const;

private:
    /// Member data:
    Return (*_m_opFunction)(Param, ParamsOther...) = nullptr;
    void* _m_opInstance = nullptr;
    /// Static member functions:
    template<class C, Return (C::*Function)(Param, ParamsOther...)>
    static inline Return _wrap_function_member(void* instance_, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_);
    template<Return (*Function)(Param, ParamsOther...)>
    static inline Return _wrap_function_static(void*, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_);
};

/// Member functions:
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>& Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::bind(Return (*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...)){
    _m_opFunction = &_wrap_function_static<decltype(function_)>;
    _m_opInstance = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
template<class C>
Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>& Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::bind(C& c_, Return (C::*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...)){
    _m_opFunction = &_wrap_function_member<C, decltype(function_)>;
    _m_opInstance = &c_;
    return *this;
}
/// Member functions (overloaded operators, function call):
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
Return Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::operator()(Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_) const{
    return _m_opFunction(_m_opInstance, param_, params_other_...);
}
/// Static member functions:
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
template<class C, Return (C::*Function)(Param, ParamsOther...)>
Return Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::_wrap_function_member(void* instance_, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_){
    return (static_cast<C*>(instance_)->*Function)(param_, params_other_...);
}
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
template<Return (*Function)(Param, ParamsOther...)>
Return Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::_wrap_function_static(void*, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_){
    return (Function)(param_, params_other_...);
}

int f(int i_){
    return i_ * 2;
}

int main(void){
    Delegate<int (int)> delegate__;
    delegate__.bind(&f);
    printf("Result: %i\n", delegate__(8));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this on **Ideone** with C++11 compiler (*GCC 4.7.2*), but it seems to fail:

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Delegate& Delegate::bind(Return (*)(Param, ParamsOther ...)) [with Return = int; Param = int; ParamsOther = {}]’:
>   prog.cpp:79:23:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:45:5: error: no matches converting function ‘_wrap_function_static’ to type ‘int (*)(int)’
>   prog.cpp:39:26: error: candidate is: template static Return Delegate::_wrap_function_static(void*, Param, ParamsOther ...) [with Return (* Function)(Param, ParamsOther ...) = Function; Return = int; Param = int; ParamsOther = {}]
>   prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Return Delegate::operator()(Param, ParamsOther ...) const [with Return = int; Param = int; ParamsOther = {}]’:
>   prog.cpp:80:40:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:59:65: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
>   prog.cpp:59:65: error: too many arguments to function

From what I can understand, **decltype** and *function pointer* here

```
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>& Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::bind(Return (*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...)){
    _m_opFunction = &_wrap_function_static<decltype(function_)>;
    _m_opInstance = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

seem to be causing the problem. Same happens when I try to bind member function to the delegate. Why is this so? What am I doing wrong? To me it seems pretty natural to get the type of the function pointer and use that type as a template argument, but for some reason, it won't work here. *What is wrong with this decltype and function pointer scenario?*

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying to do. You pass a function pointer to `bind`, but `bind` never uses the value of its parameter. Do you somehow plan to be able to call the passed function later?

Comment: `template<Return (*Function)(Param, ParamsOther...)> static inline Return _wrap_function_static /*...*/` Is expecting a function pointer as non-type template argument. `&_wrap_function_static<decltype(function_)>` provides a function pointer type as template argument.

Comment: Oh btw. why don't use use `std::bind` and `std::function`?

Comment: I don't think you can combine your `bind` and the your wrap mechanism: `bind` doesn't have the function pointer as a non-type template argument and therefore only has access to the pointer at run-time. Your wrap-mechanism requires access to the pointer at compile-time (to instantiate the appropriate wrapper). You could replace the wrapping (which essentially only differentiates between member and non-member functions) with a check `_m_opInstance == nullptr` but IMO the design is arguably flawed.

Comment: @DyP: "bind doesn't have the function pointer as a non-type template argument and therefore only has access to the pointer at run-time". Now I see the problem, templates cannot be resolved at runtime, only on compile time. Sad, but understandable reason. But why doesn't the compiler detect this error instead of "no matches converting function ‘_wrap_function_static’ to type ‘int (*)(int)'? Is it too difficult for compiler to figure it out here? By the way, why do you think the design is arguably flawed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the first part of the error messages from clang++ 3.2:

```
temp.cpp:41:19: error: assigning to 'int (*)(int)' from incompatible type
      '<overloaded function type>'
    _m_opFunction = &_wrap_function_static<decltype(function_)>;
                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
temp.cpp:75:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'Delegate<int
      (int)>::bind' requested here
    delegate__.bind(&f);
               ^
temp.cpp:35:26: note: candidate function has different number of parameters
      (expected 1 but has 2)
    static inline Return _wrap_function_static(void*, Param param_,...
                         ^


temp.cpp:55:41: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 2
    return _m_opFunction(_m_opInstance, param_, params_other_...);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                ^~~~~~
temp.cpp:76:38: note: in instantiation of member function 'Delegate<int
      (int)>::operator()' requested here
    printf("Result: %i\n", delegate__(8));
```

This occurs because of the declaration of `_m_opFunction`:

```
Return (*_m_opFunction)(Param, ParamsOther...) = nullptr;

template<Return (*Function)(Param, ParamsOther...)>
static inline Return _wrap_function_static(void*, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_);
```

That is, `_wrap_function_static` expects a `void*` then the arguments to forward to the function call whereas `_m_opFunction` only expects the arguments for the function call.

---

The Standard Library solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int f(int i_){
    return i_ * 2;
}

struct foo
{
    int m;
    int f(int i) { return i * m; }
};

int main()
{
    std::function<int (int)> delegate__;

    delegate__ = f;
    std::cout << "Result: " << delegate__(8) << std::endl;

    foo o;
    o.m = 21;
    delegate__ = std::bind(&foo::f, std::ref(o), std::placeholders::_1);
    std::cout << "Result: " << delegate__(2) << std::endl;
}
```

---

Trying to fix your approach:
Note: You cannot convert from a member function pointer to an "ordinary" function pointer (it may work using unions or copying the raw data... UB). A better approach would be to use polymorphism (i.e. virtual functions & dynamic allocation of a caller object).

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename>
class Delegate;

template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
class Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>{
public:

    /// Constructors & destructors:
    Delegate(void) = default;
    Delegate(Delegate const& delegate_) = default;
    Delegate(Delegate&& delegate_) = default;

    /// Member functions:
    Delegate& bind(Return (*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...));
    template<class C>
    Delegate& bind(C& c_, Return (C::*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...));

    /// Member functions (overloaded operators, assignment):
    Delegate& operator=(Delegate const& delegate_) = default;
    Delegate& operator=(Delegate&& delegate_) = default;

    /// Member functions (overloaded operators, function call):
    inline Return operator()(Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_) const;

private:
    /// Member data:
    Return (*_m_opFunction)(Param, ParamsOther...) = nullptr;
    Return (Delegate::*_m_opMemFunction)(Param, ParamsOther...) = nullptr;
    void* _m_opInstance = nullptr;

    /// function wrappers:
    template<class C>
    static inline Return _wrap_member_function(Delegate const&, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_);
};

/// Member functions:
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>& Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::bind(Return (*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...)){
    _m_opFunction = function_;
    _m_opMemFunction = nullptr;
    _m_opInstance = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
template<class C>
Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>& Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::bind(C& c_, Return (C::*function_)(Param, ParamsOther...)){
    _m_opFunction = reinterpret_cast<decltype(_m_opFunction)>( &_wrap_member_function<C> );
    _m_opMemFunction = reinterpret_cast<decltype(_m_opMemFunction)>( function_ );
    _m_opInstance = &c_;
    return *this;
}
/// Member functions (overloaded operators, function call):
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
Return Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::operator()(Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_) const{
    if(nullptr == _m_opMemFunction)
    {
        return _m_opFunction(param_, params_other_...);
    }else
    {
        auto f = reinterpret_cast<Return (*)(Delegate const&, Param, ParamsOther...)>( _m_opFunction );
        return f(*this, param_, params_other_...);
    }
}
/// function wrappers:
template<typename Return, typename Param, typename... ParamsOther>
template<class C>
Return Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)>::_wrap_member_function(Delegate<Return (Param, ParamsOther...)> const& instance_, Param param_, ParamsOther... params_other_){
    Return (C::*memFuncPtr)(Param, ParamsOther...) = reinterpret_cast<decltype(memFuncPtr)>( instance_._m_opMemFunction );
    return (reinterpret_cast<C*>(instance_._m_opInstance)->*memFuncPtr)(param_, params_other_...);
}

int f(int i_){
    return i_ * 2;
}

struct foo
{
    int m;
    int f(int i) { return i * m; }
};

int main(void){
    Delegate<int (int)> delegate__;
    delegate__.bind(&f);
    printf("Result: %i\n", delegate__(8));

    foo o;
    o.m = 21;
    delegate__.bind(o, &foo::f);
    printf("Resilt: %i\n", delegate__(2));
    return 0;
}
```

---

Why I said "the design is arguably flawed":

- Standard Library already contains a "delegate" type (`std::function`)

  - Order of arguments is different for member functions in StdLib bind (`std::bind(&A::func, instance)` vs `delegate__.bind(instance, &A::func)`)
  - StdLib bind copies the instance, you have to explicitly use `std::ref` (or a pointer) to pass a reference <- less error prone because it's obvious you have to keep the instance alive until the function is called
- function call copies parameters (better: perfect forwarding)
- Why splitting up the parameters in `Param` and `ParamOthers`?
- incompatible to functors

Comment: Thank you very much, I see now. However, didn't I already do default init the function pointers to 0? Like in "Delegate(void) = default;"? I also initialized fptrs in the class scope. Am I missing something? Well, anyway, there are tons of casts, but casting is basically what this seems to be all about. I like std::function & std::bind example, helps me to compare different approaches, even though I think my syntax is more user-friendly. Have to add functor and lambda support, though. I'll see how it goes and if something goes wrong, you'll probably find me asking questions here once again. :D

Comment: @Helixirr Well you could wrap `std::function` and `std::bind` if you don't like their syntax. Ad init of fct ptrs: [class.ctor]/6 "The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer" (same for explicitly defaulted ctor) non-static data members w/o brace-or-equal initializer and which also don't occur in the ctor-initializer will be default-init; but you need value-init (-> zero-init) to set the fct ptrs to `nullptr`.

Comment: I wonder why the function pointer initialization is like that. Wouldn't it make more sense if it would work the way I did it? And yeah, thanks for the tips, a wrapper might be a good idea.

Comment: @Helixirr That has nothing to do with function pointers. Every data member of non-class type w/o explicit initializer (`int`, `bool`, `my_type*`, ...) won't be initialized at all with default-init, _you don't pay for what you don't need/use_. Value-initialization for those types leads to zero-initialization, but that requires an explicit initializer (like `my_type::my_type() : int_member{}`)